# Prevent file being overwritten during CakePHP bake

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I'm working on a particularly complex (read: fun) CakePHP project, with a large number of foreign keys, join tables, etc. Definitely a case for using **cake bake**.

However, as I build the app, I'm gradually adding customisations, such as virtual fields, to my models. The development throws up the need for changes in other models/tables, so I often need to rebake.

Is there a way of protecting certain models (or controllers, views) from being overwritten while still using the **all** flag? I'd rather not rebake each dependent model from the command-line to avoid the overwrites.

Suggestions would be welcome.

(**edit:** for clarity, I'm referring to entering a command such as **cake bake model all**, but in some way flagging a small number of models to be ignored)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using 'bake' a lot, so this is not a direct answer to your question.

I usually hand-code my code from scratch. However, you may consider putting your project under version control (e.g. SVN or GIT). After a successful 'bake', you can 'commit' a version and check the changes after the next bake. Unwanted changes made by the 'bake' process can then be 'reverted', or previous changes can be merged with changes that *are* wanted

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't really cater for what I'm after (I already use source control and can do reverts if needed, but this is complicated if you're halfway through a set of changes when you need to bake). Upvote for the useful suggestion though.